# jQuery UI Tabs not rendering with upgraded UI version

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I'm upgrading my jquery libraries from a very old 1.2.7 to 1.9.1. I'm able to get most of the functionality working except for the UI tabs. I created a jsfiddle with my code that is not working as it used to with the old jquery lib.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LXbAa/

The problem is when I try to call a function using following syntax:

return '#tabs > ul';

this is where it doesn't work as expection

The code is as follows:

```
var Tabs = {
    init: function(){
       this.tabs = this.getTabs();
       // this.bind();
    },

    getTabs: function() {
        return $(this.tabNode()).tabs({
            ajaxOptions: { global: false}
       });
    },
    tabNode: function() {
          return '#tabs > ul';
     }
}
```

TIA.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LXbAa/1/  is this the fiddle you meant to use?

Comment: @Rooster, yes it is. I had another open SO tab open and posted stuff related to this to that thread! Oooopsie!  Anyways, so for some reason the tabs are not being rendered.

Comment: so wait are you saying my fiddle resolves your issue?

Comment: Not if remove/comment out the following:     $("#tabs").tabs();

Comment: What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: OK so with jquery v1.2.6, the following code works: var Tabs = {
    init: function(){
        this.tabs = this.getTabs();
       // this.bind();
    },
    
    getTabs: function() {
        return $(this.tabNode()).tabs({
            ajaxOptions: { global: false}
        });
    },
    tabNode: function() {
        return '#tabs > ul';
    }

    
} But with jquery version 1.9, it doesn't. Now if I subsitute the tabNode() function with $("#tabs").tabs(), then it works fine. My questions was what is wrong with the code "as is", without $("#tabs").tabs?

Comment: $('#tabs').tabs() initializes the jquery ui tabs object.  The other part of the code just creates an object.  I think you probably haven't included some other bit of code as that code by itself shouldn't do anything.  you would have to do something like Tabs.init();

Comment: @Rooster, you sure were right! There is a Tabs.init() in another file called app.js! Now the question becomes, why wasn't that Tabs.init()in app.js firing off and rendering the tabs that were being defined in the file called tabs.js? Could it be that there may be an error in tabs.js that is preventing the initializing? Just thinking out loud here. The rub is that IE8 debugger doesn't show any error though!

Comment: Probably a deprecated function somewhere.  is that commented out bind function actually commented out in your production script?

Comment: Oh no, there's a shinola load of bindings in there. Chrome's debugger provides me the actual xhr info, and it is pointing to the tabs & app.js files, but not sure at this point what the offending code is. The ajax calls seem to be off as well, in the upgraded code vs the old jquery library.

Comment: actually I was wrong, bind should still work fine in jquery 1.9+  do a find in files for the 'live' jquery method.  If you have any of those in there they will cause trouble.  or any of these: http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: Rooster, thx for that but I already removed all the occurences of live() and monkey-patched it with on(). But since the gap is so huge between 1.2.6 and v1.9.1, there could be some stragglers of other deprecated syntax as you suggest. This is the error I get in chrome's debugger: 'Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined' and points to jquery-ui-1.10.2.js but also points to a custom function in tabs.js, checking that now, will update you soon.

Comment: I wonder if this chunk of custom code is causing the issue: return $("#highs_tabs").tabs({
   ajaxOptions: { global: false },
   select: function() { $('#spinner').show() },
   load: function() { $('#spinner').hide() }
  });